# Several mutexes locking in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

In many places there is a suggestion to use std::defer_lock:

```
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk1(mutex1, std::defer_lock);
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk2(mutex2, std::defer_lock);
    std::lock(lk1, lk2);
    //Do some stuff
}
```

But what if I won't use std::defer_lock, and try to do simply that:

```
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk1(mutex1);
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk2(mutex2);
    //Do some stuff
}
```

As far as I know, this code will lock mutex1, and then lock mutex2. Unlocking will be performed in the reverse order - mutex2, and then mutex1. There is no reason to deadlock.

Documentation says, that std::lock(lk1, lk2); in the first example would lock buth mutexes simultaneously. So, is this some sort of optimization?

Comment: In this case, there should be no need for the deadlock-avoidance that `std::lock` does.

Answer (score 0):

The deadlock issue is a problem of the order of locking several mutexes.  This might be apparent in easy applications, but very difficult in more (or too?) complex situations where the mutexes may not always be locked at the same function and they are usually not called lk1, lk2,... so by locking simultaneously, you don't create a situation where two threads wait on locked mutex, hence being unable to unlock the mutex they locked.

You might want to avoid mixing mutexes, but that can lead to other tricky situations.  However when possible, it is best to let threads work on independent state and let 1 controlling thread accumulate the result.